# Use group seperator(GS) in hive external table as delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am using the following query to create an external table with group seperator(GS) as delimiter

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS icephase2Demo.GS_TEST1
(
RandomString1 String,
RandomString2 String
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\35'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/DataSourcing/DV_POC/GS_TEST/';
```

Then I am loading data from the file

```
load data inpath '/DataSourcing/DV_POC/groupseperatorOutput.dat' into table icephase2Demo.GS_TEST1;
```

The following is the input in my file

[image]

but when i issue select command in hive , I am getting the values concatenated

```
hive> select * from GS_TEST1;
```

nAUrLJdXYKFw       NULL

I9X24g8mqIMQ       NULL

\35 is the octal value of group seperator. its ascii value is 29.
I understand that the delimiter '\35' is not picked by hive.

Please suggest a work around for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `\29` (decimal), `\035` (octal) or `\u001D` (hex)

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between \35 and \035

Comment: `\0` indicates octal, otherwise it is decimal